# GROUP By in Django ORM for page in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset

I'm not very long in Django, sorry for the probably stupid question.
But after many hours of trying to solve and a huge number of searches on the Internet, I did not find a solution.

My Models:

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey()<..>
    # other fields
```

```
class OfferViewCount(models.Model):
    offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer, verbose_name=_('Offer'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_agent = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('User Agent'), max_length=200)
    ip_address = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('IP Address'), max_length=32)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The database of the OfferViewCount model has the following data:

```
id;user_agent;ip_address;created_date;offer_id
24;insomnia/2022.6.0f;127.0.0.1;2022-11-18 14:14:52.501008+00;192
25;insomnia/2022.6.0z;127.0.0.1;2022-11-18 15:03:31.471366+00;192
23;insomnia/2022.6.0;127.0.0.1;2022-11-18 14:14:49.840141+00;193
28;insomnia/2022.6.0;127.0.0.1;2022-11-18 15:04:18.867051+00;195
29;insomnia/2022.6.0;127.0.0.1;2022-11-21 11:33:15.719524+00;195
30;test;127.0.1.1;2022-11-22 19:34:39+00;195
```

If I use the default output in Django Admin like this:

```
class OfferViewCountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('offer',)
```

I get this:

```
Offer
offer #192
offer #192
offer #193
offer #195
offer #195
offer #195
```

I want to get a result like this:

```
Offer;Views
offer #192;2
offer #193;1
offer #195;3
```

Simply put, I want to display one instance of each duplicate post in the admin, and display the total number of them in a custom field.
In SQL it would look something like this:

```
SELECT offer_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM offer_offerviewcount GROUP BY offer_id ORDER BY COUNT DESC;
```

I've tried many options, including overwriting get_queryset.
In general, I managed to achieve the desired result like this:

```
class OfferViewCountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('offer', 'get_views')
    list_filter = ['created_date', 'offer']
    list_per_page = 20

    def get_views(self, obj):
        return OfferViewCount.objects.filter(offer=obj.offer).count()

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = OfferViewCount.objects.filter(
            ~Exists(OfferViewCount.objects.filter(
                Q(offer__lt=OuterRef('offer')) | Q(offer=OuterRef('offer'), pk__lt=OuterRef('pk')),
                offer=OuterRef('offer')
            ))
        )
        
        return qs

    get_views.short_description = _('Views')
```

But in this case, sorting by Views does not work.
If I add it explicitly via admin_order_field for get_views, I get an error because there is no such field in the database.
To avoid such an error, it is necessary to fasten the overwritten annotate queriset, something like this:

```
qs = OfferViewCount.objects.filter(
    ~Exists(OfferViewCount.objects.filter(
        Q(offer__lt=OuterRef('offer')) | Q(offer=OuterRef('offer'), pk__lt=OuterRef('pk')),
        offer=OuterRef('offer')
    ))
).annotate(_views_count=Count('offer'))
```

And change `get_views` to:

```
def get_views(self, obj):
    return obj._views_count
```

But in this case, `Count('offer')` always returns 1, probably because not the entire base is analyzed there.

Actually, tell me, please, how to add a working sorting?
If there is some much simpler way (without `~Exists` and constructions with `Q()|Q()`).

Comment: Check this one https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/sorting_calculated_fields.html

It might help.

Answer (score 1):

**you should use the Django group by like below**

```py
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = OfferViewCount.objects.values("offer")
    .annotate(count=Count("offer")).distinct().order_by("count")
    return qs
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Using .values() ​​gives me the error: Cannot call select_related() after .values() or .values_list().

Comment: call select_related() before .values()

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help, the error still appears. I can't figure out what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use below queryset for group by query

```
from django.db.models import Count

def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = OfferViewCount.objects.values(
            'offer'
        ).annotate(
            offer_count=Count('id')
        ).order_by("-offer_count")
    return qs
```

In mysql raw query like,

```
SELECT 
`offer_offerviewcount`.`offer_id`, 
COUNT(`offer_offerviewcount`.`id`) AS `offer_count` 
FROM `offer_offerviewcount` 
GROUP BY `offer_offerviewcount`.`offer_id` 
ORDER BY `offer_count` DESC
```

But if you use **admin default change_list template** then this query gives you an **error**. Because django admin when render values in template expect **list of objects in queryset** and group_by query return in queryset as **list of dict**.

If you want to use above query, then you **override change_list template and rendered data itself**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If I use your solution, I get an error: TypeError at /admin/offer/offerviewcount/
Cannot call select_related() after .values() or .values_list() (even if override change_list_template to empty html)

Comment: Error message says you can't apply select_related() after values(). So first you apply join if any join needed then call .values('offer') for group by query.

Comment: This error appears when I use .values(). No other join is applied. I removed all unnecessary code. What else can it come from?